# Google Map on Android appears blank

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented a map with google maps in my ionic project. In browser works perfect, but in android doesn't work. The map appears blank with the Google logo.

My code:

```
    LocationService.getMyLocation().then(async (myLocation: MyLocation) => {
      let options: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
          target: myLocation.latLng,
          zoom: 15
        }
      };
      this.gmap = await GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', options);

    });
  }
```

I've the API key for android in config.xml

`<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="XXXXXXXX" />`

On browser works well:

[image]

but nothing appears on android

[image]

I've compiled the app with the command **ionic cordova run android --l**

Comment: Can you check if your API key has restrictions on it?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of google native you are using?

Did you read this post? at certain point it refer to tabs layout, which seems to create problem. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-google-maps-plugin/139786/13

Try to follow this guide: https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-google-maps-sdk-cordova-plugin-in-ionic-4-application/